# Rotate SCNNode infinitely 360°

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm looking for a way to rotate a note 360 degrees around its z-axis. The node holding the camera moves negatively along the z-axis and is not allowed to change its y & z.
I've already tried a `CABasicAnimation`, but without success.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: This `cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1.f, cameraNode.presentationNode.rotation.w + DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(.5f));
` gives me a weird effect, like snapping back to 0 after 90°...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Also, please clarify what you mean by "is not allowed to change its y & z".

Comment: like falling down a tunnel but only in negative z direction, x & y are supposed to stay 0, just thought I should mention this

Answer (score 8):

How about rotating it by less than 360°? Since your title says "infinitely" it should work just fine, and repeating the animation over and over will justend up being 360° and more.

Else, you can look at Apple's default SceneKit project, which works great for me:

```
[cameraNode runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:.5 z:0 duration:1]]];
```

Or, for OSX:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"rotation"];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithSCNVector4:SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 1, M_PI*2)];
animation.duration = 15;
animation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT; //repeat forever
[YOURNODE addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

Comment: If doesn't have any effect when I apply this to my `cameraNode`. Trying this on `cameraNode.camera` give me this error message: `[SCNKit ERROR] rotation is not an animatable path (from <SCNCamera: 0x14ed5470>)`

Comment: Hum, it seems CA doesn't work on iOS. This is not really my strongest platform, so sorry for misleading you.

I have updated the code with something that works for me!

Comment: I ended up using eulerAngles and am very happy :) but thank you very much for your help and merry Christmas!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Have a merry Christmas as well!

Answer (score 8):

To rotate an object forever along z-axis.

```
let node = SCNNode()
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
//creating an box object
node.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
node.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
//adding a rotation by Z axis        
let action = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 0, z: CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(360)), duration: 8)
let forever = SCNAction.repeatForever(action)
node.runAction(forever)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[ZnodeOnly physicsBody] setVelocityFactor:SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 1)];

[[ZnodeOnly physicsBody] setAngularVelocityFactor:SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 1)];

[RotatingNode runAction:[SCNAction repeatActionForever:[SCNAction rotateByAngle:-360/(180/M_PI) aroundAxis:SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 1) duration:1]]];
```

`[node setRotation:(x,y,z, w)]` is an instant transformation.
using SCNAction animates the rotation.